# show details on selected row

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a window form which consist of 2 datagridview, customer and order. When the customer cell is being double click, i would like to get the current row customerID and query in on nw.orders which have the same customerID. Unfortunately, the LINQ result always return empty. May i which part i did wrong? Or any other alternative way to retrieve the order for that particular customer? Thank for viewing and advise in advance.

```
public partial class CustomerOrder : Form
{
    northwindEntities nw;

    public CustomerOrder()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CustomerOrder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        nw = new northwindEntities();
        customerBindingSource.DataSource = nw.Customers;
    }

    private void customerDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string CustID = (string)customerDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value;

        ordersBindingSource.DataSource = from order in nw.Orders
                                         where order.Customer.CustomerID == CustID
                                         select order;
    }
}
```

Comment: The query looks fine to me. I would double check the data in the db and what value is in the `CustID` variable.

Comment: Oh. My bad. The problem was Cells[1] is not CustID. Thanks for the help.